# Wordpress and MySQL Collations

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, collation

I'm just having this trouble with Wordpress: I use to have a Blog with and older version of it and of MySQL, and when I export the SQL DB Creation Scripts, they exported with the latin1_swedish_ci Collation.

Know I'm trying to rebuild the blog but it shows a lot of strange characters like:

```
ImaginarÃ© CreativitÃ¡
```

When It must show: Imaginary Creativity.

I'm on a mac and using TextMate. I try to convert the SQL Script from batch by using:

```
iconv -f latin1_swedish_ci -t utf8 script.sql > newscript.utf8.sql
```

But it tells me that:

```
iconv: conversion from latin1_swedish_ci unsupported
```

So, What else can I do in order to convert the file? Or can I program a routine with any script language?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a couple of weeks ago and this plugin saved me:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/utf-8-database-converter/

Run this before exporting the database and you should be ok.

PS: of course, backup everything before using the plugin!

Comment: Hi Vinicius and thanks for the answer.. the problem is I already exported the db script.

Comment: Are you using the --default-character-set=latin1 when importing in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

If your blog was created before WordPress 2.2 then you should not be using `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` in your wp-config.php file.

See [Editing wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) for more information.